# EclipseLink JPA uses a non-entity as target entity in the relationship attribute

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, junit, eclipselink

I'm getting the following error when I'm running my test in JUnit (version 4.12) to make a order:

```
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2c7b84de
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [snel-transport-test] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.OrderLine] uses a non-entity [class nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Product] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field product].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.services.AbstractFacade.getEntityManagerFactory(AbstractFacade.java:31)
    at nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.services.AbstractFacade.find(AbstractFacade.java:77)
    at controller.OrdersControllerTest.testAddOrder(OrdersControllerTest.java:345)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [snel-transport-test] failed.
```

However when I run the webapp it does work when I make a order.

Below you can see the code:

OrderLine.java:

```
@Entity 
public class OrderLine implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @TableGenerator(
            name = "OrderLineGenerator",
            allocationSize = 1,
            initialValue = 1)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE,
        generator="OrderLineGenerator")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "orderId")
    private Long orderId;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Product.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="productId")
    private Product product;
    private int amount;

    //More code..
}
```

Product.java:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @TableGenerator(
            name = "ProductGenerator",
            allocationSize = 1,
            initialValue = 1)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE,
            generator="ProductGenerator")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="Name")
    private String Name;
    @Column(name="Price")
    private Double Price;
    @Column(name="code")
    private String Code;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="categoryId")
    private Category Categories;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", targetEntity = nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.OrderLine.class)
    private List<OrderLine> orderLines;

    public Product(){

    }

    public Product(Long Id, String name,String code, Double price, Category categories) {
        super();
        id = Id;
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
        Code = code;
        Categories = categories;
    }

    //More code..
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="snel-transport" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Orders</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.OrderLine</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.OrderList</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Customer</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Product</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Category</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Status</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Truck</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Route</class>
        <!-- <jta-data-source>java:app/snel-transport</jta-data-source> -->
        <!-- <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> -->
        <properties>
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="create" />
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage"
                value="dev" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
                value="META-INF/sql/insert.sql" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation-target"
                value="database" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/snel-transport" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="transport_user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
                value="admin" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="snel-transport-test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Orders</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.OrderLine</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.OrderList</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Customer</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Product</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Category</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Status</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Truck</class>
        <class>nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Route</class>
        <properties>
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="drop-and-create" />
            <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage"
                value="test" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
                value="META-INF/sql/insert.sql" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation-target"
                value="database" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/snel-transport-test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="transport_user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
                value="admin" />
            <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

As you can see I have already clearly marked `Product` and `OrderLine` as entities through using the `@Entity` annotation in 
`Product.java` and in `OrderLine.java`. I have also listed both classes in the `persistence.xml` file.

I can remove `mappedBy` in `Product.java` which fixes the problem, but I don't want this because I don't want to create an extra table.

I have already checked these solutions:

[jpa error uses a non-entity [class ch.printsoft.mailhouse.usermgr.entity.Department] as target entity in the relationship attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353752/jpa-error-uses-a-non-entity-class-ch-printsoft-mailhouse-usermgr-entity-departm)

[JPA EclipseLink uses a non-entity as target entity in the relationship attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408259/jpa-eclipselink-uses-a-non-entity-as-target-entity-in-the-relationship-attribute)

[EclipseLink - non Entity as target entity in the relationship attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422993/eclipselink-non-entity-as-target-entity-in-the-relationship-attribute)

But I couldn't find something that would solve my problem. Anyone that has a clue how I can fix this?

Comment: If it works one spot, but not another, it is likely a classpath issue.  Check your classpath when running in JUnit that you don't have some other non-entity Product class file being picked up, or a different persistence.xml where product might be missing.  Also set EclipseLink logging to finest, as it will show each class as it deploys it for the persistence unit.

Comment: @Chris Thanks I had indeed another persistence.xml file.. If you want you can post your comment as an answer so I can accept it as the solution for my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it works one spot, but not another, it is likely a classpath issue.

Check your classpath when running in JUnit that you don't have some other non-entity Product class file being picked up, or a different persistence.xml where product might be missing. Also set EclipseLink logging to finest, as it will show each class as it deploys it for the persistence unit

Answer (score 1):

The error

> [class nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.OrderLine] uses a non-entity [class nl.cimsolutions.snel_transport.models.Product] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field product].

Means that the product field in OrderLine refers to a Product which is not part of the persistenceContext. Typically this occurs because EntityManager.persist() was not called on Product, and there was no Cascade.Persist which automatically persists it.

It is a bit hard to imagine that this could be a classpath issue, but I have seen stranger things. I think you should start by checking the persist logic related to the Product store in OrderLine.product.